VBA code to iterate through report pages in ms access
I need help with a VBA code that can iterate through report pages within microsoft access.
I tried using the code below to iterate through the pages but it was only able to iterate through record set then I thought my aim is to iterate through a page not recordset.
Sub splitreport()

   Dim MyFileName       As String
   Dim rst              As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strReportName    As String
   Dim strOutPutFile    As String
  
  
   strReportName = "Unpaid_Invoice"
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Unpaid_Invoice")
  
   Do While rst.EOF = False
     
  
      strOutPutFile = "C:\Users\AAAAA & rst!BROKERNAME & ".pdf"  ' output file = BROKERNAME.pdf
      DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewPreview, , "ID = " & rst!Id
      DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportName, acFormatPDF, strOutPutFile
      DoCmd.Close acReport, strReportName
     
      rst.MoveNext
     
   Loop
  
   rst.Close
  
   MsgBox "Report Download Completed"

End Sub

Result: Creating files of report with individual rows instead of a page with more than 3 to 5 rows.

Take a look at report.page event.
